# How to write a function that adds numbers in a list by calling itself?

Tags: python, list, recursion, sum

I'm trying to write a function that adds up all the numbers in a list but by calling itself in Python. Here's an example of what I mean:

```
def factorial(n):
   if n == 1:
      return 1
   else:
      return n * factorial(n-1)
```

How would you use this to find the sum of a list?

Comment: The sum of a list is `sum([list])`... but that doesn't appear to be what you're asking or what you've just been answered.

Comment: @Ben Sure, but this is clearly a homework-type question on the use of recursive functions, and I suspect jamylak's first answer is pretty close to the model solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
nums = [1, 3, 2, 8, 9]
def rec_sum(nums):
    if not nums: return 0
    return nums[0] + rec_sum(nums[1:])

>>> rec_sum(nums)
23
```

You could even do this in one line:

```
def rec_sum(nums):
    return nums[0] + rec_sum(nums[1:]) if nums else 0
```

To avoid all the shallow copies of the list being made `nums[1:]` on each call you can do something more efficient:

```
def rec_sum(nums, i=0):
    if i >= len(nums): return 0
    return nums[i] + rec_sum(nums, i+1)
```

It's also fun to use the [Y-Combinator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator#Y_combinator)

```
>>> Y = lambda f: (lambda x: x(x))(lambda y: f(lambda *args: y(y)(*args)))
>>> rec_sum = lambda f: lambda nums: nums[0] + f(nums[1:]) if nums else 0
>>> Y(rec_sum)(nums)
23
```

Comment: Thanks, jamylak!! The first three were what I was looking for. I was trying to do the third code you wrote on my own, but couldn't figure out how to make it loop. the rec_sum(nums, i+1) was what I was missing.
Thanks for the extra knowledge, also!